# "Unknown database 'mydb' " error with jpa

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

i'm trying to connect to mysql server but get this error. when mydb is the only name in the system. please tell me where i'm wrong...

my persistence xml is as folow:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd"
 version="1.0">

 <persistence-unit name="MyPersistenceUnit">

  <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>

  <properties>
   <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class" />
   <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
   <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb" />
   <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root" />
   <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="tft" />
   <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />

   <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />

   <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
   <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
   <property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments" value="true" />
  </properties>

 </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: Isn't something wrong with the persistence.xml you show ? Or at least, that's what my eyes tell me ;-)

Comment: Is your DB up? Are you able to connect using some other client? What is the complete exception stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

1.You have to check your mysql jdbc driver

2.You have to check mysql server state and validation of username & password.